# How to move all dxi-column of dx-data-grid to separate component?

Tags: angular, typescript, dx-data-grid

We are developing angular application. We have used dx-data-grid to display data. Here I want to customize the data fields. Is it possible to move all column lists to separate component?

Any one please help to achieve the same.

Thanks

Krishnan

Comment: I would like to do the same, have you find any solution ?